# How to change the End Date based on Start Date in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have start date and end date.

If I change start date then end date automatically set as one month forward.

means I selected start date as 21-05.2015

I need to set end date as 20-06-2015

any suggestions please.

Comment: change it how? Not much info given. Might be as simple as a change event handler. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Keep a watch on start date. Inside watch compute the one month forward date and assign it to End Date. Something like this :

```
$scope.$watch('startDate', function(startDate) {

    if (angular.isDefined(startDate)) {

        $scope.endDate = //get One Month Forward Date

    }

}, true);
```